# How to add label to top of stage

Tags: javafx, label, scene

I am trying to place the "Registration form" text at the top but when I do pane.add it separates the spacing between the labels and textfield boxes. How do I add it to the top without it affecting everything below it?

```
public class RegistrationForm extends Application {
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

GridPane pane = new GridPane();
pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
pane.setPadding(new Insets(11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5));
pane.setHgap(5.5);
pane.setVgap(5.5);

Text text = new Text ("Registration Form");
text.setFont(Font.font("Times New Roman", FontWeight.BOLD, 
FontPosture.ITALIC, 20));
pane.getChildren().add(text);

pane.add(new Label("User Name: "), 0, 1);
pane.add(new TextField(), 1, 1);
pane.add(new Label("Password: "), 0, 2);
pane.add(new TextField(), 1, 2);
pane.add(new Label("Email: "), 0, 3);
pane.add(new TextField(), 1, 3);
pane.add(new Label("Phone: "), 0, 4);
pane.add(new TextField(), 1, 4);
Button btReg = new Button("Register");
pane.add(btReg, 0, 5);
GridPane.setHalignment(btReg, HPos.LEFT);
Button btCan = new Button("Cancel");
pane.add(btCan, 1, 5);
GridPane.setHalignment(btCan, HPos.LEFT);

Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
primaryStage.setTitle("Registration Form");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();        
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Docs

> add(Node child, int columnIndex, int rowIndex, int colspan, int
>   rowspan) Adds a child to the gridpane at the specified column,row
>   position and spans.

You should use:

```
pane.add(label, 0, 0, 2, 1);
```